# Freezing Model drops Output Accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow

I have a image segmentation network designed to classify roads and obstacles. I want to freeze the model and serve it as a API. So I used the default TensorFlow tool for freezing the model. After freezing, the output given by the network are completely off and inaccurate.

Here is one sample.

**The Input Image**

[image]

**Output when tested using Checkpoint files**
[image]

**Output after Freezing the Model**
[image]

I have tried to freeze using different versions of tensorflow, but that has not helped. Since the network is performing as excepted when tested against checkpoint, the issue, I think is in the Freeze Models Script. The network uses Batch_normalisation. Could this be the reason for this drop because I saw a couple of issues linked to that of similar nature? How can I avoid that?

[Here's](https://pastebin.com/ydxReqNf) the full network

**Prediction Using Checkpoint Files**

```
with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
    images_tensor = tf.train.string_input_producer(images_list, shuffle=False)
    reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
    key, image_tensor = reader.read(images_tensor)
    image = tf.image.decode_png(image_tensor, channels=3)
    image = preprocess(image)
    images = tf.train.batch([image], batch_size = 1, allow_smaller_final_batch=True)

    #Create the model inference
    with slim.arg_scope(ENet_arg_scope()):
        logits, probabilities = ENet(images,
                                     num_classes=4,
                                     batch_size=1,
                                     is_training=True,
                                     reuse=None,
                                     num_initial_blocks=num_initial_blocks,
                                     stage_two_repeat=stage_two_repeat,
                                     skip_connections=skip_connections)

    variables_to_restore = slim.get_variables_to_restore()
    saver = tf.train.Saver(variables_to_restore)
    def restore_fn(sess):
        return saver.restore(sess, checkpoint)
    predictions = tf.argmax(probabilities, -1)
    predictions = tf.cast(predictions, tf.float32)
    sv = tf.train.Supervisor(logdir=None, init_fn=restore_fn)
    with sv.managed_session() as sess:
        for i in xrange(int(len(images_list) / 1 + 1)):
            segmentations = sess.run(predictions)
            for j in xrange(segmentations.shape[0]):
                converted_image = grayscale_to_colour(segmentations[j],i,j)
                imsave(photo_dir + "/imagelabel_%05d_edges.png" %(i*1 + j), converted_image)
```

**Prediction from PB File**

```
def predict():
    start = time.time()
    y_out = persistent_sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: x_in})
    end = time.time()
    print(end-start)
    return y_out

with tf.Session() as sess:
    model_filename = "frozen_model_tf_version.pb"
    with gfile.FastGFile(model_filename, 'rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def)
        g_in = tf.get_default_graph()

x = g_in.get_tensor_by_name('import/batch:0')
y = g_in.get_tensor_by_name('import/ENet/output:0')

persistent_sess = tf.Session(graph=g_in)
x_in_unaltered=cv2.imread(img)
x_in_unaltered = cv2.resize(x_in_unaltered,(480,360),interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
x_in = np.expand_dims(x_in_unaltered.flatten(),axis=0)
predictions=predict()
print(np.unique(predictions,return_counts=True))
out = np.array(predictions[0],dtype=np.float32)
out = np.reshape(out, [360,480])
converted_image = grayscale_to_colour(out,x_in_unaltered)
cv2.imwrite("out.png",converted_image)
```

Comment: you need to add code related to this issue.

Comment: @IshantMrinal Do you mean the NN Graph? Cause I have used the default freeze model tool in tensorflow by `python -m tensorflow.python.tools.freeze_graph --input_graph graph.pb --input_checkpoint test_model --output_graph graph_frozen.pb --output_node_names=y`

Comment: the model definition file (where u defined tensorflow layers etc) and the two predictions codes

Comment: @IshantMrinal I updated the post. Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the problem is related to `is_training`, since you are using `dropout` and `batch_norm`, during prediction time `is_training` shoudl be set to `False`. then you can expect same results.

```
logits, probabilities = ENet(images,
                                 num_classes=4,
                                 batch_size=1,
                                 is_training=False,
                                 reuse=None,
                                 num_initial_blocks=num_initial_blocks,
                                 stage_two_repeat=stage_two_repeat,
                                 skip_connections=skip_connections)
```